# Matching variables in two Vectors and making an Map of the comparison in an efficient way

Tags: c++

I have written a bit of code to match two vector of objects that have some of the same instances of objects within both of the vectors.

The idea is to find the index of the object in the 'main' vector and match that to the object of the other vector.

The index of the main vector would then be used in a map with that object.

I think looking at the code may make my explanation a bit clearer:

```
ifndef OBJECTMAPMATCH_H
#define OBJECTMAPMATCH_H

#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

namespace ObjectMapMatch {

  ...
  ...
  template< class A, class B >
    std::map<int, B*>*  getIndexMap( std::vector<A*>* x , std::vector<B*>* y,  std::map<int, B*>* output )
     {
      typename std::vector<A*>::iterator Aitr  = x->begin();
      typename std::vector<A*>::iterator AitrE = x->end();
      typename std::vector<B*>::iterator Bitr  = y->begin();
      typename std::vector<B*>::iterator BitrE = y->end();

      for(int index=0; Aitr!=AitrE; ++Aitr, ++index){
        //Keep track of original index
        int AntupIndex = (*Aitr)->Index();
        int match = false;

        for(; Bitr!=BitrE; ++Bitr){
           int BntupIndex = (*Bitr)->Index();

           if( AntupIndex == BntupIndex ){
              match = true;
              output[index] = (*Bitr);
            }
           } //End of loop B

           if(!match){
             std::cout << "ERROR:ObjectMapMatch::getIndexMap: Can not Find Match" <<  typeid(y).name() << " FOR " << typeid(x).name() << std::endl;
             exit(1);
            }

           }//End of Loop A

          }

   ...
   ...
}
#endif
```

As you can see I am basically comparing the two objects with there unique index and if this matches the object will match.

My quesitons:

I know I could have overloaded the comparison operator in the object class, but I was not sure if something like this would be correct??

```
bool operator==(object1& lhs, object2& rhs){
   &lhs == &rhs ? return true : return false;
}
```

Also,

Is there a shorter/more efficient way of the above code using some STL algorithms (can not use the boost libs) or something smarter??

Mike

Comment: @perreal - yes this would work. ;-D. Any ideas about any STL efficiency solution's of matching these objects. the loop solution is ugly...

Comment: A general note: You should pass objects by reference, not pointer in C++ whenever possible. It simplifies the syntax and makes it clear that the receiver is not getting responsibility for the life-cycle. You should also use const wherever you don't modify the object. Most C++ libraries are designed for const correctness and will pass objects as const, so your code won't work without.

Comment: In the example above the method should be `std::map<int, B*> const & getIndexMap( std::vector<A*> const & x , std::vector<B*> const & y,  std::map<int, B*> & output )` and the operator has to be `bool operator==(object1 const & lhs, object2 const & rhs)`. The later is because the standard library will be calling it on const references, so operator taking non-const ones would not match. Of course such `operator==` won't compile if the `Index` method is not defined with `const` modifier (const for invocant goes after the argument list).

Comment: @Jan Thank you for your comments. I agree const correctness should be added to this code! One problem I have with passing by reference however is when these objects are on the heap so new has been used. woudld I then need to de-reference the pointer and then pass it by reference. This can get messy if I need to do a deep copy. Any thoughts??

Comment: @MWright: You should use reference for *passing* the objects around to functions like this. If the object has separately allocated parts, they will probably be still stored as pointers and the object will be stored in most data structures also as pointer. But in cases where you don't need the pointer features (like this function that just looks at those two vectors and does not keep them, modify them etc.), you should use reference to signify that you don't use pointer features. It takes some time to get used to it, but eventually it makes reviewing the code a lot easier.

Comment: As for `new`, that's in fact another thing you should try to use as little as possible. Good C++ code contains few `new`s and even fewer `delete`s (uses `std::auto_ptr` or the newer `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` instead). Of course you need `new` for polymorphic objects, but otherwise you can often embed collections of values as value members and save yourself some trouble managing memory.

Comment: @Jan does the share_ptr not use the new operator if the reference to the object is 0, that is just a guess...but yes I agree with your suggestion. I should aim to use new only when wanting polymorphic behavior. I will try to keep to these techniques

Comment: @MWright: shared_ptr does not create the object, it just counts it's uses and deletes it when done. You create it with `new` and it's exactly the case when you do use `new`, but leave the `delete` on something that ensures it will happen when you are done with the object. C++ generally has many ways to make it manage memory for you, usable in different circumstances and they will save you lot of trouble if you learn to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do this more efficiently than O(n^2).

For example:

- Sort elements of the first vector.
- Sort elements of the second vector.
- Use `set_intersection` on sorted vectors.

Or:

- Put elements of **both** vectors to `multiset` (or `unordered_multiset`).
- Keys of the `multiset` that have **more than one** element indicate a match.

For both of these methods, you could use pointers or indexes in original vectors instead of the actual elements. Just be careful to provide comparer (to `sort`, `set_intersection` and `multiset`) able to deal with pointers/indexes.

Comment: both vectors are sorted with the same condition. I am not sure how set_intersection would work with my problem, as I want to store the index of vector A to a map[int, B ]. this is so I know which object number in vector A refers to the object in vector B. sorry if that was not clear

Comment: @MWright: Than you'll have to write the indices to the sorted structure. But I strongly suspect that needing the index is a sign of suboptimal design somewhere higher up the call chain. In fact the whole problem looks like you might be using suboptimal data structures.

Comment: @Jan The reason I need the index is to refer to it later in the code, but I do agree I should rethink think this methodology. Thanks Jan